# llvm-objdump how to find whether debugging infomation

Tags: clang, llvm, clang++, llvm-ir

I have a set of llvm IR byte code object files.
I have found that '-g', option in the llvm-objdump will print the debugging information in the binary.

```
# llvm-objdump -g  llvm-ir-binary.o
```

but it just only showed the help info , but no any source level debugging information. Is there any other tool or is that the correct option to make it happen ?

Comment: somebody please be kind enough to help me in this issue.

Comment: `-g` doesn't work on llvm-objdump currently.